# Sort pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a Dataframe with a MultiIndex by using another Dataframe:

```
arrays = [df['bus_uid'], df['bus_type'], df['type'],
          df['obj_uid'], df['datetime']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['bus_uid', 'bus_type', 'type',
                                                 'obj_uid', 'datetime'])
multindex_df = pd.DataFrame(df['val'].values, index=index)
```

This worked fine as described in the documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html .

In the documentation it also says that the labels need to be sorted for the correct working of indexing and slicing functionalities under "The need for sortedness with MultiIndex".

But somehow

```
multindexed_df.sort_index(level=0)
```

or

```
multindexed_df.sort_index(level='bus_uid')
```

does not work anymore and throws *TypeError: sort_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'level'*.

Looking up the object information on *sort_index()* it looks as "by" is my new friend instead of "levels":

```
by:object
  Column name(s) in frame. Accepts a column name or a list for a nested sort. A tuple will be interpreted as the levels of a multi-index.
```

My question is the following: How can I sort my MultiIndex so that all functionalities (slicing,etc.) are working correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on the pandas version you are working with. With the **latest pandas (>= 0.17.0)**, you can indeed use the `level` keyword to specify to sort which level of the multi-index:

```
df = df.sort_index(level=0)
```

But, if you have an **older pandas (< 0.17.0)**, this `level` keyword is not yet available, but you can use the `sortlevel` method:

```
df = df.sortlevel(level=0)
```

But note that if you want to **sort all levels**, you don't need to specify the `level` keyword, and you can just do:

```
df = df.sort_index()
```

This will work for both the recent and older versions of pandas.

---

For a summary of these changes in the sorting API, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-sorting-api

Comment: My mistake! I was working on version 0.16.2 and now updated to 0.17.1. So just applying *multindex_df.sort_index(inplace=True)* is enough to get all functionalities?

Thanks!

Comment: Slicing from the ordered index now pops up an error: 1. "idx = pd.IndexSlice" 2. "subset = multindex_df.loc[idx[['el: DE22C'],['el'],['input'],:,:]]" brings ""KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (5), lexsort depth (0)'"

Comment: My mistake again. I forgot to sort the index after recreating ;) Thank you such much!